# Allow read-write access to subdirectory in first local account to second local account

Tags: security, filesystem, sharing, authorization

I have two accounts (one for work, the other for private stuff) on a Mac, which is running OS X Yosemite. I would like to share a directory, say `~work/Documents/SomeDirectory/SomeSubDirectory/`, such that the other account (say `~home`) can read from and write to it.

I know how to do this with Unix access control, but I don't want to go through the trouble of creating groups and checking all the parent directories.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this by using OS X `Sharing & Permission` settings (those accessible under `Get Info` in the Finder). If so, how would I go about sharing `SubDirectory` between the two accounts with minimal effort (yet also minimal exposure to third accounts and esp. remote users.)

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use `/Users/Shared`? Simply create a directory in it and create two aliases of it one for each of your users. This is the most simple way just using Mac OS and the Finder. The access rights of the original directory unter `/Users/Shared` can by edited by finders information dialog (add the other user with read/write access).

Comment: +1 because it's workable, but I'd like to keep the subdirectory under `~work/` for reasons related to backup, etc. The `Sharing & Permission` settings for `/Users/Shared` are instructive.